# Where to find detailed doc on functions?

Tags: octave

To find doc on function `zeros` right click on function within Octave UI and select Documentation. This give some information on the function but does not detail the meaning of parameters.

e.g this code :

```
z = zeros(2, 2);
```

creates 2x2 Matrix of zeros.

But what does this invocation mean and where to find its documentation ?:

```
z(1, :) = z' ?
```

Comment: `'` means transpose `z(x,y) = ` means indexing (set the element at position x,y from matrix `z`). You should probably read the documentation of octave.

Comment: you're having issues understanding the core language syntax, that's not a function. You need to read the [Octave manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/).

Comment: @Steffen To be precise, `'` is the hermitian transpose (transpose and complex conjugate). This boils down to simple transpose only for real data. For simple transpose, `.'` should be used (mind the dot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading manual I discovered help function, here is output of run from command line :

[image]